# Integrating apollo-client with angular JS application

Tags: angularjs, apollo-client

I tried integrating apollo-client into my angular application and it worked wonderfully.

However, my manager asked to call the GraphQL server from our prototype application called 'protoApp'  which was built in Angular1. So I followed your documentation in https://github.com/apollographql/angular1-apollo

1. I did `npm install angular1-apollo apollo-client --save` . I could see the angular1-appolo, apollo-client, graphql-tag modules under node_modules.
2. Now, when i add 'angular-apollo' as a dependency into my app module, it is failing when i ran this application -

   ```
   (function () {
       'use strict';
       var apolloAng = require('angular-apollo');
       angular.module('protoApp', [
           'ngAnimate',
           'ngResource',
           'ui.router',       
           'anugular1-apollo'
       ]);
   })();
   ```

In the browser, i am seeing

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=CompassApp&p1=Error…0yc%20(http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A9090%2Fscripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)

I tried first requiring the module using require('angualr-apollo') and then injecting into angular module , i am seeing Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

3. How to add import statements when defining default client when i have to import gql from graphql-tag, as import statements are not working in my angular1 application.

Comment: did you get this working?